# how to make "likes button"?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

What I would like to do is, place a button below an user posting which the another user can press. Once pressed it will increment a like value in the database for the like table. Problem is I have no idea how to make it base on my query to show posting. this below is table name and it field that i have :

`user` : id_user, username

`posting`  : id_post, id_user, content

`like`  : id_like, id_user, id_post

and this below is query to show posting :

```
$query=$dbc->query("select user.username, posting.content FROM posting inner join user on user.id_user = posting.id_user where id_post='$_GET[id]'");
$array= $query->fetch_array()
```

Comment: You would like to show likes or increase like counts ?

Comment: i would it like facebook likes button. i have make it show different button after clicked, than now i need to insert record to increase like counts

Comment: hey, it's different post. your answare is using ajax

Comment: Your question seems not to be hard. but isn't clear enough